# Fastest G protein coupled reactions

Tags: kinetics

As per few [references](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11343651), fastest G protein coupled reaction known is *Drosophila melanogaster* phototransduction which produces quantum bumps with average latency of 45 ms (and peak response around 200 ms). Another reaction is chemotaxis which is also in that order. I was wondering are there any known examples which are as fast as these responses?

P.S: Many ion channels are GPCR which triggers very fast but most of them takes long time (in order of seconds) to give peak ion concentration

P.S.S: By fastest I mean, minimum time required to give peak response after activation of receptor(s).

**Update:**

*In abstract case*, Let's say you got signal from outside at time t = 0. Now this will leads to reaction cascade which will take time 't1'. Assume output of this is opening of channel which will increase concentration of ion X. Now X will reach it's peak concentration at time t = t1 + t2. So I am looking for such reaction cascades with minimum time 't' (t1+t2).

Comment: That is not the property of the receptor. There are many other factors that dictate the response time (the time required to achieve steady state).

Comment: Yes. I am asking for smallest reaction times which involves GPCRs. And it need not be steady state. Peak time is not steady state.

Comment: Even peak time is a function of a lot of different parameters. Btw peak can be observed only in case of certain network architectures. A single reaction doesn't peak; you need a feedback (or some other kinds of motifs). Anyways, what do you exactly mean by reaction time? What is the reaction here. There can be several downstream effects some of which can be early while others are delayed.

Comment: Why do you want to know this? A little context might make the question more answerable.

Comment: @WYSIWYG , I think you didn't get my question (or I didn't explained properly). Let's say you got signal from outside at time t = 0. Now this will leads to reaction cascade which will take time 't1'. Assume output of this is opening of channel which will increase concentration of ion X. Now X will reach it's peak concentration at time t = t1 + t2. So I am looking for such reaction cascades with minimum time 't' (t1+t2).

Comment: @GoodGravy , I just wanted to know smallest time delay between signal and response in GPCR.

Comment: @Dexter but there can be several steps in a cascade and some of them might take more time than the others to reach the peak. What I am saying is that the response is not just dependent on the receptor but also on the other molecules interacting with it. Not only that; initial conditions, the magnitude of the signal etc also matter.

Comment: @WYSIWYG, exactly. There will be many steps which will ideally create time delay for output of particular signalling cascade. I am looking for such time period. Assuming all other interactions are also involved in setting up this delay, I was curious to know how fast these reactions can be.

Comment: So does this question boils down to "What is the shortest GPCR reaction, i.e. with the receptor and effector being separated by a minimum number of steps?"

Comment: I wouldn't say minimum number of steps. Time required to execute all these steps should be minimum.

Comment: @Dexter I don't really understand what is the purpose of the question. Curiosity or you are looking for parameters for your mathematical model? In any case nobody has checked all the GPCR pathways. The number of downstream steps and also the architecture of the network determine the response time. An example of long term effects of GPCR signalling would be growth, which might take many hours to reach steady state. That would be the maximum limit. Olfactory/visual stimulus should be the fastest because these are quickly converted to electrical signals.

Comment: It's my curiosity. I had heated discussion with my friends on same topic. So I wanted to know scientifically what is reality.

Answer (score 2):

Mammalian rod cells, the most numerous photoreceptor cells in the retina, reach a max depolarization after a single photon stimulus at 100-120 ms, implying a time constant (1/k) of about 25 ms (see Chen et al., Nature 404:557).  This is on the same order of speed as the fly eye, maybe a tad faster.  Non-photoreceptor GPCRs are probably slower, but few folks have tried to measure these effects. The m1 muscarinic acetylcholine receptor catalyzes Gq activation with a time constant of about 500 ms (Mukhopadhyay and Ross PNAS 96:9539), but there may be faster ones.

Comment: *Drosophila* photoreceptors are way faster than rod cells. Check out reference I provided in question.